# Can mapreduce work efficiently over a shared tuple space (eg: a database)?

Tags: mapreduce

I am asking this as I am wondering if it could be efficient to run mapreduce queries over a database or a shared keyvalue store?

For example, to implement a web trawler, which indexes the internet and counts all the terms on different web pages, could this be done efficiently with a database as a backend?

Comment: It might be better to put your "can MapReduce do X?" questions together, rather than posting several.

Comment: Ok, thanks @skaffman, I'll rephras the question

Comment: Have you had a look at how Nutch does this? http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/

Comment: Yes, I have looked at how Nutch does this, but it doesn't run over a database, it runs over hadoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  HBase and other NoSql stores are well suited for this task.

See this [article](http://www.larsgeorge.com/2009/05/hbase-mapreduce-101-part-i.html) for a general overview of using HBase with MapReduce.

> HBase is the Hadoop database. Use it
>   when you need random, realtime
>   read/write access to your Big Data.
>   This project's goal is the hosting of
>   very large tables -- billions of rows
>   X millions of columns -- atop clusters
>   of commodity hardware.
>
> HBase is an open-source, distributed,
>   column-oriented store modeled after
>   Google' Bigtable: A Distributed
>   Storage System for Structured Data by
>   Chang et al. Just as Bigtable
>   leverages the distributed data storage
>   provided by the Google File System,
>   HBase provides Bigtable-like
>   capabilities on top of Hadoop. HBase
>   includes:
>
> •***Convenient base classes for backing
>   Hadoop MapReduce jobs with HBase
>   tables***
>
> •Query predicate push down via
>   server side scan and get filters
>
> •Optimizations for real time queries
>
> •A high performance Thrift gateway 
>   •A REST-ful Web service gateway that
>   supports XML, Protobuf, and binary
>   data encoding options
>
> •Cascading source and sink modules
>
> •Extensible jruby-based (JIRB) shell
>
> •Support for exporting metrics via the Hadoop
>   metrics subsystem to files or Ganglia;
>   or via JMX